# Number changes when converting Double to Numerics.BigInteger

Tags: .net, double, biginteger

```
using System.Numerics;

double doubleNumber = Math.Pow(1000, 99); // = 1.0E+297
BigInteger bigBase = (BigInteger)bigNumber; // = 1000000000000000017652801462756379714374878780719864776839443139119744823869255243069012222883470359078822072829219411228534934402712624705615450492327979456500795456339201761949451160807447294527656222743617592048849967890105831362861792425329827928397252374398383022243308510390698430058459037696
```

**Why is the `BigInteger` value not just 1 kagillion (1,000 followed by a bagillion 0's)?**

Comment: Haha, I just learned some new words: kagillion and bagillion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of BigInteger uses a lot of bit shifting, so when you convert a double to a BigInteger, the double representation has a finite set of bits (64 bits in for a double), so not all the bits are there to accurately represent the value.

Instead of using Math.Pow, you should be using

```
var bigBase = BigInteger.Pow(1000, 99);
```

Also, explicitly casting a numeric type to a BigInteger is the same as using the BigInteger constructor:

```
 var bigBase = (BigInteger)doubleNumber;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var bigBase = new BigInteger(doubleNumber);
```

Comment: Imho this answer is wrong. This has nothing to do with bit shifting in BigInteger but with the floating point representation of `Math.Pow(1000, 99)` is **not** `1.0E+297` but one of the nearest representable values in the fp representation.

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) only has 15 decimal digits of precision, which means the value will be *close* to the actual value, but might not be precise.

It all has to do with how floating point values are encoded in order to occupy a fixed amount of memory.

This is exactly the same problem which lets `1.0` end up as `0.999999999999999999etc`.

If you need absolute precision, you need to use a library/type which has that, `double` has not.

For your specific code, you might want to do this:

```
BigInteger bigBase = BigInteger.Pow(1000, 99);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more precise version of `double Math.Pow()` function?

Comment: Well, yes, there is [BigInteger.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow.aspx). I've edited the answer to reflect this.